# unable to install foundation using cli

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, npm-install, zurb-foundation-6

i am trying to install foundation 6 cli.
this is the error i get.
[image]

Please tell me what is wrong here.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've never installed a previous version of the Foundation CLI and are using `Windows` as your primary `OS`, errors like these are usually due to improper user permissions and/or level of access.

I'd recommend attempting the install with `elevated` access (i.e. opening your `cmd` prompt as the `Administrator` via `right-clicking` on the app and selecting the `Administrator` option).

If all else fails, the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command will be your best bet. The answer **[here](https://superuser.com/a/42540)** breaks it down even further.